# Hammer.js and jQuery confusing classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hammer.js, animate.css

I am trying to make a web app that would run on my phone. I am using the Hammer.js library for recognizing touch gestures and animate.css for the animations. I use the `swipeleft` and `swiperight` touch recognizers to change the classes of certain `div` elements. however when I use `swiperight` and then `swipeleft` (while testing it on chrome or my iphone) it gets the classes mixed up and the elements are in the wrong position.

Here is some of my code

index.html

```
<div class="container" id="app">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10 co-xs-offset-1 col-md-4 app_card active_app_card animated id="app2">
            <!-- More code -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10 co-xs-offset-1 col-md-4 app_card animated id="app1">
            <!-- More code -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-10 co-xs-offset-1 col-md-4 app_card animated id="app3">
            <!-- More code -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

stylesheet.css

```
 .app_card {
      position: absolute;
      right: -100%;
 }

 .active_app_card {
     right: auto;
     left: auto;
 }
```

main.js

```
$(function() {
var app1 = document.getElementById("app1");
var app2 = document.getElementById("app2");
var app3 = document.getElementById("app3");

Hammer(app1).on("swipeleft", function() {
    console.log("app1 left");
    $("#app1").addClass("slideOutLeft");
    $("#app2").addClass("bounceInRight active_app_card").one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {
        $("#app1").removeClass("slideOutLeft active_app_card");
        $("#app2").removeClass("bounceInRight");
    });
});

Hammer(app2).on("swiperight", function() {
    console.log("app2 right");
    $("#app2").addClass("slideOutRight");
    $("#app1").addClass("bounceInLeft active_app_card").one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {
        $("#app2").removeClass("slideOutRight active_app_card");
        $("#app1").removeClass("bounceInLeft").addClass("active_app_card");
    });
});
```

The problem is when I swipe right when `app2` is onscreen, and then swipe left when `app1` is onscreen, the animation works and `app2` comes onscreen, but as soon as the animation is over, `app2` disappears and `app1` comes back. if I swipe left again, `app2` comes on screen properly. Is there anyway to stop `app1` from appearing when I swipe away from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have solved this problem by not starting a new animation before the current is over. I hav already changed the code a lot so I cant post the exact code again(it would probably cause some confusion). Basically what I did was set up a variable that is true while an animation is running. so when hammer detects a swipe, it will check the variable to see whether the animation is currently running or not.

here is a simplified form of the code

```
window.animating = true;

Hammer(app).on("swiperight", function() {
    if ( window.animating === true ) {
        console.log("animation currently running");
    } else {
        //next animation code
    }
}
```